# Is it possible to create an abstract carousel component that rotates through any components?

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

I have been tasked with creating a React component that is able to rotate through a carousel of any array of components. It also needs to be responsive.

Is this even feasible granted that it needs to work with an array of components which will likely have different sizes? On the bright side, all of the components in the array are guaranteed to have the same dimensions, but I'm not sure where to even start with this.

This is what I mean by carousel btw:

[image: Amazon Carousel]

Comment: Is it possible? Yes: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel

Comment: @EvanTrimboli that only displays one item at a time though

Comment: slidesToShow React.PropTypes.number Number of slides to show at once. Will be cast to an integer when transitionMode="fade"